# Attach maven goal to phase via command line

Tags: java, maven

TL;DR: Is it possible to attach a plugin goal to a particular phase **without** specifying the phase in the plugin's `<phase>package</phase>` brackets, **but** by passing this information somehow via the command line?

The reason I'm asking this, is because I am using the maven-release-plugin, and another plugin which produces some report files, and I am attaching these report files to the current build via the `build-helper-maven-plugin`'s `attach-artifact` goal, which is supposed to run during the `package` phase. But I do not want to attach the plugins in the pom file to certain phases, because **I have to be able to build and install locally on my machine without the plugins being run**, which would automatically happen if I were to run for example the  `install` goal. The plugins should only be run when building and deploying on the Jenkins machine, so I am using a Groovy script to run the goals of the maven-release-plugin.

So in theGroovy script, the maven-release-plugin goals are being run in this order:

`clean` `prepare` `perform`

The documentation tells me, that the `package` phase is part of the `perform` goal, so the plugin's `attach-artifact` goal needs to be executed in this phase.